# Can't creake a package on fuerte

Tags: ros, catkin-package, catkin, ros-fuerte, build-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run this [example](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes).  To do, I should create a package. But I can't create the package on ros-fuerte.

There are two ways package build type named catkin and rosbuild. Which one I should?

I tried both of them. My fuerte workspace is under home folder. Using catkin;

```
fuerte_workspace$ catkin_create_pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs
Created file using_markers/CMakeLists.txt
Created file using_markers/package.xml
Created folder using_markers/include/using_markers
Created folder using_markers/src
Successfully created files in /home/user/fuerte_workspace/using_markers. Please adjust the values in package.xml.
```

Next step is :

```
You should be able to build the code with:
 $ cd %TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_WORKSPACE%
 $ catkin_make
```

I don't have any catkin workspace(or I can't find it). So, I tried to create a workspace using this [guide].(http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace).  But `catkin_init_workspace` doesn't work. Error message is `fuerte_workspace$ catkin_init_workspace command not found` .

How can I create a package on fuerte?

**EDIT**

I tried rosbuild+fuerte. The guide says that

```
Before getting started, let's create a scratch package to called using_markers, somewhere in your package path:
roscreate-pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs
```

I tried `roscreate-pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs` command, and I got an error. Error mesaage is below :

```
fuerte_workspace$ roscreate-pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/roscreate-pkg", line 34, in <module>
import roscreate
 File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscreate/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
import roscreate.core
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscreate/core.py", line 40, in <module>
import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212572/can%27t-creake-a-package-on-fuerte/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess this error now comes from missing python-setuptools. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Then, call roscreate-pkg again.

But I'm with cyborg-x1 on this: Don't use Fuerte anymore. If you are on 12.04 and cannot upgrade due to whatever reason, try to go to Hydro at least.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-06-30**:
I tried this command, everything is up-to-date. `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 181 not upgraded.`

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-06-30**:
I use lsd_slam, it tested only fuerte(ubuntu 12.04) and indigo(ubuntu 14.04).

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-06-30**:
Well, I suggest you upgrade the 181 not upgraded packages anyway ;-)
But then I don't know what could be the problem.

maybe try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources python-setuptools --reinstall
```

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-07**:
You might also give pip a shot.

`pip install -U setuptools --upgrade`

Also, fuerte is EOL. Is there a particular reason you're sticking with Fuerte?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess fuerte was the distribution before catkin arrived.
So when I am right there are no catkin commands in fuerte.

Actually that means if you are continuing to use fuerte (I am not sure if that is recommended) you would have to use rosbuild instead of catkin.

(May anybody correct me if I am wrong)

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-06-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-06-30**:
I tried rosbuild. I just edit my question text. I can't create a package using rosbuild.